# XSD with "required" attribute option related query

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to XSD and XML and need to explore if there is option to make sure that any one attribute in a set of attributes within same element is required.

Example:

xs:element name="condition" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"

```
                  xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="alias1" use="required"
                  xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="col1" use="required"
                  xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="operator" use="required"
                  xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="string" use="optional"
                  xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="number" use="optional"
                  xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="date" use="optional"
```

Here I want to ensure that minimum one  attribute  in a set of 3 attributes (mentioned as optional in above) are required. All can not be optional , however any one (can be more than one also) is required.

Thanks,
Rajneesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done in XSD 1.0. It can be done in XSD 1.1 using assertions, for example

```
<xs:assert test="count(@alias1, @col1, @operator, ...) ge 1"/>
```

Comment: Hello Michael, I am working inside the database, it won't be possible.

Oracle XML DB only supports XML Schema 1.0.

Comment: Then it can't be done, unless you have influence to persuade Oracle to get up to speed with their standards conformance.

Comment: Thanks Michael, it helps. one more help please: Is it possible to impose required constraint at value level?for example I want  to make sure value for alias1, coli1 and operator is always populated in condition element within where element: <where>
<condition alias1="CFTY" col1="CODE"  operator="="  string=""   number="" date= ""    />
</where>

Comment: below is respective xsd part for example-

xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="alias1" use="required"
xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="col1" use="required"
xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="operator" use="required"

Comment: Please don't ask supplementary questions in comments on the answer to a different question. Accept the answer, and open a new free-standing question.